# Coinbase "convert" API?

Tags: api, script, coinbase.com, trade

[image]

I use the convert functions at coinbase to take advantage of market changes to increase my position amounts.

This weekend I am going to write a php script that tracks the available conversion pairs and makes charts & notifications when a coin you are holding has increased in price and swapping coins may be beneficial.

Example: 5 BCH = 8 ETH.  BCH increases by 5%, now 5 BCH = 8.4 ETH.  You make the swap and wait.  BCH retraces AND/OR ETH increases in price... Maybe now 8.4 ETH = 5.06 BCH.

The end result in the example is an increase of .06 BCH.

Does Coinbase offer an API for the convert functions?  Could not find it...